# HttpClient PostAsync to Blogger API

Tags: c#, rest, oauth, blogger, dotnet-httpclient

I am using the following API to allow me to interact with Google Blogger. I need to insert a post into the users blog. However I am having trouble with my PostAsync functionality. I get a 401 telling me that my request isn't authorized despite having an API Key, however I think I may not be properly inserting my OAuth token.

I have the following code,

This is the code where I set up my authorization header, (note the key there is fake but is the same form as what i think is the OAuth token)

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("ya29.AHES6ZTBZi1dWPVdlcF7qAD-nSM6XxwY2323232m4lXW");
```

And this is my PostAsync function

```
                HttpResponseMessage response = await req.PostAsync(URLs.postBlogURL + blogID + URLs.postBlogURLPost, new StringContent(json));
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong? Cheers.

[**UPDATE**]

I amen't sure whether the authorization has to include the string bearer in it.

```
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer ya29.AHES6ZTBZi1dWPVdlcF7qAD-nSM6XxwY2323232m4lXW");
```

Comment: Is there a way to independently verify your API key? Also, try checking the content of the response, it *may* include some additional diagnostic information.

Comment: Yeah I can do a get request that requires the API just fine. So it's definitely down to the post requests. I just have the feeling that I amen't setting up the authorization header correctly for my HttpClient.

Comment: How are you doing a `GET` request? In a web browser or using HttpClient?

Comment: Have you used Fiddler (or something similar) to compare your working GET request and failing POST?

Comment: @Snixtor as far as I know I amen't doing any GET request. I authenticate using 'WebAuthenticationResult' and 'WebAuthenticationBroker'.

Comment: *"I can do a get request that requires the API just fine"* and *"as far as I know I amen't doing any GET request"* Your latest feedback is kind of confusing. You have, or have not managed to perform a `GET`? If you haven't gotten a `GET` request to work yet, I'd recommend working on that first, as there's fewer things to get right (or get wrong).

Answer (score 25):

This is how I was able to get the proper OAuth auth header set for my request:

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue( "Bearer", _accessTokenWrapper.Token.access_token );
```

The first parameter to the constructor is the scheme to use for the Authorization header.  So in the request, the header reads:

```
Authorization: Bearer {the access token string}
```

Comment: Hi @Scott can you please post the code for the accessTokenWrapper class? I'm interested in creating a global store for the token value. Thanks

Comment: What namespace and NuGet package would I get the class that you use to create that _accessTokenWrapper object?